# PHP long running scripts in sequence

Tags: php, timeout, file-get-contents, long-running-processes

I have the following problem : in a php script, I have to launch a first script, then a second one. The second one ***must not start before the first one has finished***.

**Problem** : the two scripts are long-running (can take up to some hours). So, if I use `file_get_contents` on each script url, I can make the first one run (via `set_time_limit 0`), but the `file_get_contents` times out, so I have an error, and the second one never runs.

**Note** : those scripts run on `localhost` on a `linux` machine, on which I am admin. I can do whatever I need to make this work.

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about PHP scripts here? Then why file_get_contents, and not include/require …?

Comment: Those are php scripts, which should be called via full url : it's in codeigniter, so it needs to respect the routing process.

Comment: use` fopen(); fclose();` or `stream_set_timeout();`

Comment: You could try and pass a stream context into file_get_contents and specify the timeout via that. (Not sure if -1 for “no timeout” is a valid option.) But that might still run into problems with timeouts on the web server level or something. A script running that long should rather not be called via HTTP in the first place IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute them via command line, and chain them with `&&`, so the second one will fire only if the first has finished correctly

```
php script1 && php script2
```

Or chain with `;` if you just want the second to trigger after the first, regardless of exit status

```
php script1; php script2
```

Comment: With exec and the &&, it's just what i needed. Thanks.